# How to avoid repetitive code in this scenario?

Tags: reactjs

I write this code. Which return true or false value according to the item included in the other array or not.

But My senior said this code is not dry. I can't think of a way to make it more DRY. Can someone help and show me a way

```
const renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
    if (favList.includes(item.id)) {
      return (
        <IndividualProduct
          info={item}
          index={index}
          key={index}
          fav={true}
          stateChange={stateChange}
          setLoading={setLoading}
          setSignInShown={setSignInShown}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <IndividualProduct
          info={item}
          index={index}
          key={index}
          fav={false}
          stateChange={stateChange}
          setLoading={setLoading}
          setSignInShown={setSignInShown}
        />
      );
    }
  };
```

The only difference between these 2 return is the true or false value for the `fav` prop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only thing that changes is the `fav` prop, so use the result of the `.includes` call there instead.

```
const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => (
    <IndividualProduct
        info={item}
        index={index}
        key={index}
        fav={favList.includes(item.id)}
        stateChange={stateChange}
        setLoading={setLoading}
        setSignInShown={setSignInShown}
    />
);
```

Another option would be to spread the variable names with the same name as the prop.

```
const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => (
    <IndividualProduct
        {...{ index, stateChange, setLoading, setSignInShown }}
        info={item}
        key={index}
        fav={favList.includes(item.id)}
    />
);
```

Answer (score 2):

ok so this way you can just make it much dryer:

```
const renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
  return (
    <IndividualProduct
      info={item}
      index={index}
      key={index}
      fav={favList.includes(item.id)}
      stateChange={stateChange}
      setLoading={setLoading}
      setSignInShown={setSignInShown}
    />
  )
};
```

so the `favList.includes(item.id)` automatically gets replaced with true or false

hope this helps